# Web application achitecture

Tags: java, web-services, web, architecture

I've to rebuild a swing based application to move it to a web environment. This application has some functionalities that already exist in another web application. I want them both to maintain the same functionalities, even those that are shared, but I don't want duplicated code.
In terms of architecture/technologies, what is the best approach to reuse as much code as I can? A third service-oriented application that controls all the business logic and have the web applications serve only as front-end? But how to avoid code duplication on the front-end?

Any feedback will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

very broad question so it's hard to give exact solution. think about separating common functionality as a different service. then both application can just redirect to it or use its api.

if that's not an option then try to separate that logic to a library that will be included in other application. good frontend frameworks allow you to do it also with frontend code (directives, plugins, validators etc)

Answer (score 0):

You could work with dependencies transforming the common utilities, access data and business rules in libraries. In first moment you can make a refactor separating tiers and responsibilities and then you can incorporate Maven in you environment to generate and start to work with dependencies.